# How are the tag FAQ selected?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, frequent-tab

There is now an [FAQ tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/faq) for tags, listing frequently asked questions for that tag. How are the questions selected and sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It counts questions with the most links, recently it was changed to count both incoming and outgoing links.

The theory is that questions that are linked often are more likely to be asked often.

Answer (score -7):

Scroll to the bottom and it will tell you.

Comment: For lazy people, this is what "the bottom" tells us: *Highly linked questions are considered frequently asked questions*. A bit more info would be nice though... Is this the only variable (number of links to a particular question)? If not can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: just stumbled on this. Not to be rude, but about which bottom are we talking exactly? I haven't found a bottom that tells me that Highly linked questions are considered frequently asked. At least not on an obvious bottom.

Comment: @joris looks like that got removed; but the tooltip for the tab will also tell you. Just hover your mouse over the faq tab to see.

Comment: Ah, there is too much information only findable by tool tips.

Comment: Just to make sure: does this count include questions which were closed as duplicates and then deleted?