# Frequently re-asked questions

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, frequent-tab

When I select a tag to search by, there is a FAQ tab that appears to be specific to that tag. How is the ordering of these questions determined?

It doesn't appear to be by votes or views, so I'm hoping that when a questions gets re-asked and flagged as such, it increases the FAQ ranking of the original question, but since there is no "already asked" flag, I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a kind of an "already asked" flag: in the form of closing a question as a dupe of another one. I guess the more it happens that a question is closed as a dupe of another one, that other one gets a higher weight in the FAQ tab.

Actually, I just found out due to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62210/how-are-the-tag-faq-selected) that the questions of the "faq tab" are selected by "being most linked to". But I guess as a question gets linked to when closed as a dupe, this (how many times a question has been the target as a closed as a dupe) still plays a part in the order.

Comment: Thanks. Not have closing privileges made it hard to figure this one out.