# Do tag FAQs work as designed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, frequent-tab

According to the tooltip, "questions with the most links" are put into a tag's FAQ. [The comments in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62213/158779) seem to confirm that. However, that does not at all seem like what I see when I look for instance at the [java](/questions/tagged/java) FAQ on Stack Overflow. Here are a couple examples:

1. [How to track an object inside an ArrayList becoming null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557767/how-to-track-an-object-inside-an-arraylist-becoming-null)
2. [Java issues with ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838143/java-issues-with-arraylist)
3. [Spring MVC - No mapping found for request URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697167/spring-mvc-no-mapping-found-for-request-uri)
4. [Persisting to MySQL using Spring Framework, Hibernate and JPA failed, not really persisting to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597059/persisting-to-mysql-using-spring-framework-hibernate-and-jpa-failed-not-really)

None of them display any questions as being linked, and #1 and #2 are neither highly viewed nor highly voted. Why are these showing up as being frequently asked?

EDIT: It appears Waffles might be a bit confused. This is understandable due to the distinct lack of [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/158779) in my original post. Perhaps now the issue will be more clear:

[image]

Comment: Weirdness; navigate through the Linked Questions on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437172/how-to-know-geographic-location-from-an-ip-address . All subsequent pages link to the first page according to Linked Questions but no link seems to be present in the actual question+answers+comments.

Comment: which FAQ are you talking about? not seeing your answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=faq&pagesize=50

Comment: top one has TONS of links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: @waffles Read that page you linked more closely.  Note my numbers bear no relation to the order they appear on the page (check the 9th, 18th, 6th, and 3rd items on the linked page).

Comment: Im looking something is a bit odd

Comment: note your list of FAQ questions is very different to the one I see, which may indicate we have a weird concurrency issue

Comment: note 2 / we dumped our cache and it is ok at the moment, but I suspect our delta update for the cache has an issue, Marc and I will investigate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do tag FAQs work as designed?

No, they did not. In particular, there were two issues:

1. The linked question list counts both incoming and outgoing links, the original implementation of FAQ only counted incoming links. It is something that causes a bit of confusion and hurts a bit.
2. The delta update process had a query of the form `select * from Link where Type = 1 and RelatedPostId = 2 or PostId = 2` ... The missing brackets caused weird and wonderful stuff to happen.

Both issues are fixed now and are deployed.