# Should Tag Wikis contain questions links?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

In the [C# Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) there is a section called FAQs

[image]

How do we decide which questions belong in this section and which one's don't and in what order? Seems pretty arbitrary.

Perhaps it should be based on votes or number of times it was linked. That way it would always be updated. Maybe it could be put on a separate tab.

Oh wait that's already there.

[image]

**So should we leave the FAQs in the wiki body or delete that section?**

Answer (score 3):

The "FAQ" tab in the main UI just lists those questions that have the most incoming links, on the theory that high linkage equals most often asked.

The list of questions in the C# Tag Wiki is hand-picked; these are the questions that the C# community has determined have broad applicability to C# developers.  It is an attempt to develop a collection of *canonical* answers.  It is curated in a more or less arbitrary fashion, but I feel that the C# folks are doing a pretty good job maintaining this list, and have the best interests of the C# community in mind.

For more examples of this, you can check out the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag and the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag.

Comment: *these are the questions that the C# community has determined have broad applicability to C# developers* really? Was there a vote I missed? I would argue that most of [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=votes&pagesize=50) would probably be better. These really look like to me a handful of few peoples faves. I'm also worried that this gives license to the smaller tags.

Comment: License to the smaller tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1203988

Comment: I don't get it.  If you believe the edit is invalid, roll it back.

Comment: sigh I did but I wasn't completely sure if I was wrong to do so. I checked C# tag as was mystified by the randomness of the FAQs I found there. But I could just be a crank so I wanted to see what others would say. So far I'm leaning on the crank side

Comment: Looks like Conrad Frix [already rolled it back](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13315101/4).

Comment: Yeah that Conrad guy is awesome. I love his avatar too. :P

Answer (score 1):

That list of links in the Tag Wiki is not the same as the FAQ tab which [is generated by SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62210/how-are-the-tag-faq-selected).

The list in the Tag Wiki is just community edited, so there are not many specific rules how it is edited, I guess some users take care of the list a bit more and therefore sort it in the one way or not another.

Answer (score 0):

It's decided by helpful users who have the ability to edit the tag wiki (and get it approved if need be).  Someone else can edit it if they think it should be changed, though I hope we don't see any tag wiki wars, those suck.  I think they're fine in the wiki body, in fact I'm not sure how the faq tab gets populated.

Comment: See [How are the tag FAQ selected?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62210/how-are-the-tag-faq-selected) for how the tab gets populated.