# Why is this question a hot question?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, hot-questions

Is Photography such a low volume site that https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56891/why-would-i-bother-to-participate-any-further-on-this-web-site (now migrated to their meta: https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4593/why-would-i-bother-to-participate-any-further-on-this-web-site ) somehow qualifies as hot? It is not a clever title to make you read something about photographs, it's exactly what it appears to be:

[image]

35 views doesn't feel very hot to me!

The question has a lot of comments, but the accepted answer to [How are questions in the 'hot' tab selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected) makes no mention of comments at all, just views, score, answers, answer score, and age.

Comment: It's all matter of amount of answers and votes. I think that two answers, each with score of 1+ are enough to make the question "hot". However, I agree it better be changed and cancel any hotness if the question itself has negative score.

Comment: I like the way how [Stack Overflow questions are protected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226304/165773) from getting into network-wide hot list - system seems to simply block them until they reach score of 5-6. For per-site hot lists this would probably be an overkill but a softer condition, like positive score, would make sense

Comment: thanks for the bounty, @gnat