# Are the hot network questions flawed?

Tags: support, hot-questions

Acording to this formular: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/232136 it is pure math that evaluates the score. While I'm not even sure I understood the impact correctly, I calculated the score of a question I asked and then calculated the score for a HNQ of the same site where mine was higher than that one has had when came into the HNQ.

How this can be? Are there additional numbers brought into the score not visible to everyone?

Take for example this one: [Can AV software make sure quarantined files never get executed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129097/56061) versus thisone: [What is protection ring -1?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129098/56061)

In the moment of this edit: first has 2 answers both 2 upvotes eacht and the op having 3 upvotes beeing psoted 2 hours ago. While the second got HNQ'd with exactly same post time and votes, except the one in HNQ has 1 score less for OP. So please fix the mentioned `if user == Zaibis` part.... (still not funny!...)

Comment: If you have a question regarding a specific situation, please make your question specific. Give both the questions and we will see if the devs have anything to say on this.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Actually my question is just if thats really jsut the formular, or if there is anythign in addition taking influence.

Comment: it's likely to be caching. But to answer your title, yes, the HNQ are deeply, deeply flawed - not because your question didn't immediately get on the list, but for all the **other** reasons you'll see if you peruse the tag for a bit.

Comment: Yes, the code surely contains `if (userName == "Zaibis") doNotShowHotQuestion();`.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Of course, if it was written better it would show it for him, and just not anyone else ;)  Oh, and it's probably tied to user ID, not name, so that he can't get around it by changing his name.

Comment: did your calculation take into account site-specific adjustment [explained eg here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246925/165773)? For example SO questions score is divided by 5, maybe similar adjustments are made to other sites

Comment: @gnat: Nope I didn't thats why I asked if this formula is really just all.

Comment: Seriously now, if you think the formula is wrong or outdated, by all means you can bring examples with links to both questions, your calculations, etc. Not just say "the grass is always greener on the other side". That is not constructive at all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I'm not claiming anything at all! I'm simply asking a question, which partial has even been answered by gnat so far.... nothing else. No reason to make bad jokes about this....

Comment: Your question got [8.5 hotness points](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bJvyp.png) while the other one got 10.5 points. Probably the sidebar is taking only those with more than 10.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: and why? From my calculations they have the same variables except in one mine has a factor of 1 more. so why my score is lower?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Ok, NOW it has a higher value, due to BEEING in the list. but when I made the edit that one was below 10 aswell + below mine.

Comment: Might be caching, e.g. the hotness points are calculated once every 5 or 10 minutes. I still doubt the system is flawed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Even if it isn't flawed, it is enough evidence to ask for clarifications, isn't it?!

Comment: Not yet. Probably the answers on the other question got the upvotes before yours, you can check it all in the profiles of the answerers.

Comment: You are jsut guessing aswell, and guessing stuff not mentioned in the formula. So my claim all that is mentioned to the formula isn't everything. This is prooven alone by the fact that you are guessing what else could be with it.

Comment: Shadow Wizard isn't guessing. He is a long time user with lots of experience on this. If he points you to the profiles of the other users to check the timeline of the votes, that is a good suggestion which might help diagnose how things went.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Well I didn't say anything against that, but saying "probabbly" is guessing by definition. So who ever he is, if he names things that could probably cause somethign it is a guess. And I didn't find anything by his guesses. What not means he is wrong. But jsut that I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: I know for sure there is cache. I don't know if 5 minutes, 10 minutes, or something else. I know for sure that if answer on the other question got upvote before yours, then yours got two upvotes, the other will be temporary "hotter" than yours due to that cache. /cc @Pat and thanks. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: what about placing a answer about it? Thats exactly what I'm asking for. And if their are other factors like that, I'd welcome it if you would mention it aswell.

Comment: That is not a bad idea. Until you posted that example answer would have been pointless, now that I have something to work with, I can indeed do that. With you soon-ish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on close inspection, and personal observations, nothing is flawed.

First, couple of facts about Hot Questions, as a background.

1. There are total of 100 Hot Network Questions at any time. The full list is split into two pages: [1](https://stackexchange.com/?page=1), [2](https://stackexchange.com/?page=2).
2. They are sorted by something called "Hotness Points", which is the result of the formula mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/232136).
3. The calculation of the HP (Hotness Points) is not "live", but rather calculated once every 7 minutes (give or take 1 minute) and then cached for the next 7 minutes.
4. The sidebar is showing 5-25 hot questions (based on available height), taken randomly from  the list, and there is a minimum threshold of 9 HP. (based on observations.)

With this in mind, let's see why [your question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129097/56061) was temporarily below [that other question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129098/56061). Let's say you checked the status at 14:30 UTC. Let's also assume the last HP calculation ran at 14:25:00 UTC, still in the 7 minutes cache range. For this, we have to look on all those profiles:

- For your question: [your reputation tab](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/56061/zaibis?tab=reputation), [answer author 1](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/80108/priyank-gupta?tab=reputation), [answer author 2](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/112290/overmind?tab=reputation).
- For the other question: [Question OP and author of a self answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/84504/thomas?tab=reputation), [answer author 2](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/84504/thomas?tab=reputation).

With this at hand, we can gather the following stats:

- Your question:
- Question itself got 2 upvotes. (**Note! Third upvote was cast at 14:25:30, half a minute after the HP calculation**)
- Answer 1 got one upvote and one downvote, net score of 0.
- Answer 2 got one upvote.
- Total: score of 2 to the Q, total score of answers: 1.
- Other question:
- Question itself got 2 upvotes.
- Answer 1 got 2 upvotes.
- Answer 2 got 2 upvotes.
- Total: score of 2 to the Q, total score of answers: 4.

So, the other question had 3 more total answers score, which gave it better HP. Since yours gathered more upvotes in the next 7 minutes, it eventually passed the other question, as you saw yourself.

Q.E.D.